# Recommendations for TimeSeries db

Tags: database, performance, time-series, column-oriented, vldb

preferably open source for storing tick info.

Comment: Not sure why someone has voted to close this completely valid question.

Comment: will the gentleman who voted to close this please explain why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[KDB](http://kx.com/) is the industry standard for this kind of thing.

Comment: it's pricey too and hence the question

Comment: Hey downvoters - perhaps you could give a reason?  The OP said "preferably open source" not "must be open source".

Answer (score 1):

Check out the list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS#Implementations .

Answer (score 0):

Python has some package for time series 'database', which uses HDF5 as the underlying 'engine'. http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/